# Programmatically prepopulate slides to print with specific slides in PowerPoint's print dialog

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint

Is it possible to achieve something like this via a VSTO PowerPoint addin:

- User presses Ctrl+P to print a PowerPoint presentation
- Print dialog shows up
- And somehow, preselect '*CustomRange*' from printing settings and prepopulate the slides text box with specific slides, e.g *1,3,5,15*

Basically,
to have this whenever a user wants to print a document:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Presentation.PrintOptions`.

For example:

```
var printOptions = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.PrintOptions;

// Set print range type to slides and add some ranges
printOptions.RangeType = PpPrintRangeType.ppPrintSlideRange;
printOptions.Ranges.Add(1, 1);
printOptions.Ranges.Add(3, 5);
```

[Small example on Github](https://github.com/didzispetkus/vsto-powerpoint-print-ranges)